# Changing the contents of a paragraph not working javascript

Tags: javascript, html

This code is designed to change the quote on a page each time it is loaded however the paragraph just remains empty.

```
<script>
(function() {
var quotes = [
    {
    text: "This is the first possible quote”"
    },
    {
    text: "This is the second possible quote”"
    },
    {
    text: "This is the third possible quote”"
    }
    ];
var quoteUse = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML=quoteUse.text;
})();
```

Comment: Check dev tools for errors (F12). Most likely your code runs before the `quote` element is available in the DOM. Move the script to before `</body>` or use `window.onload = function(){ ... }` wrapper.

Comment: Thank you I moved it to the end and now it works perfectly

Comment: Why are you putting the quotes in the array as objects? Just put strings in the array...

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment due to low rep, but [your code seems to be working](http://jsfiddle.net/8MJpy/). Make sure the element with `id="quote"` exists and check the console for errors.